# Montgomery multiplication -- algorithm question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am a beginner, but I think I understand how to do Montgomery multiplication. Also, there are online calculators (for dummies like me)... But I have a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8638618?casa_token=GC5QO-FI0VkAAAAA:pzOe0cjG0CZwJ2hlrcm3xj8loEM7Y7rSpIMLkR3d98H9p9S8cN1lJ48iDm1ltpOInJ2ETLwy) in front of me, that is all about how to compute

$28510 · 38762\; \text{mod}\; 36057 = 23831$

Am I taking crazy pills? Isn't it $29684$ that they were supposed to get? I don't think they could write the entire paper and get the core of it wrong...

Comment: I calculated it a few times - I keep getting what the authors calculated.

Comment: I can’t access the paper, but yes, my calculator agrees that $(28510\cdot 38762)\bmod36057=29684$.

Comment: b is 38672... it is funny that this error is so consistent across the whole paper...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.01121

Comment: So, has there been a question about the algorithm, and is it settled, now?

Comment: It is settled, the algorithm is right, but the paper has propagated a typo throughout the whole draft, which was very misleading for an immature me...